# Linear independence of finite subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that a set $S$ of vectors is linearly independent if and only if each finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent.

My progress: I have been able to prove that if $S$ is linearly independent then every subset of it is too.

How to show the converse?

I'm assuming $S$ to consist of subsets $S_1,\cdots S_n$ and since each are linearly independent the result follows.

Question: Is it ok to assume that $S_1,\cdots S_n$ are disjoint? If not, can someone tell me how to prove the result in that case?

Comment: Do you mean $S = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_n$, with each $S_i$ a finite set? That would mean that $S$ itself is finite, so it is its own finite subset and there's nothing to prove. If $S$ is infinite, then you can't partition it into a finite number of finite subsets.

Comment: And even if you partition $S$ into subsets, each of which are linearly independent, that still doesn't make $S$ itself linearly independent. (For example, you can partition any set into singleton sets, and as long the null vector is not part of the set, each singleton is independent - but that doesn't make the whole set independent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's suggested approach is not helpful.

The key to this problem is the definition of linear independence of an infinite set: every linear combination of its elements *with finitely many nonzero coefficients* (not all of them zero) cannot yield the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is actually a "tautology": Suppose $S$ is not linearly independent. Then there exists non-zero vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i=0$ with some $a_i \neq 0$. But that implies that $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ is not linearly independent finite set inside $S$- contradiction.